# How can I discover what apps are currently running on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I discover, programmatically, what apps are currently running on Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot see what other apps are running on the phone. This isn't possible with the current APIs, and isn't intended ever to be possible.

Such information would only be useful for spy/malware, so there's little need to expose it.

(And no, you don't need a Android style Task Manager on Windows Phone)

Comment: @Claise jorgensen: That means we will not find out which process is running ?

Comment: For the record this wouldn't just be useful for spy/malware. It'd be really useful for advertising and cross app promotion.

Comment: @MattLacey That's what malware is in my book ;-)

Comment: @MattLacey, advertising based and cross app promotion very easily cross the line into an invasion of privacy. That doesn't go over well with end users.

Comment: *"Such information would only be useful for spy/malware..."* - Random number generators can benefit from it. OpenSSL, Botan and a number of other security libraries use it to gather bits.