# How to list running processes in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to know  list of running processes in Windows Phone 7?

Comment: Stop asking this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679250/how-to-know-the-which-activity-is-ruuning-in-windows-phone-7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131994/how-can-i-discover-what-apps-are-currently-running-on-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, Currently there are no API's provided by Microsoft to list all the running processes. May be in future if its provides then you can do so.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply  @Santhu.in windows mobile 5/6 is it posiible?

Comment: ya, its possible in Windows mobile 5, 6 and in 6.5.

Comment: use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot this api to create current snapshot and then traverse the list with Process32First, Process32Next api's

Comment: You can use the this link for your reference http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IsApplicationRunning.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Santhu?By using that can we track the incoming sms,ougoing sms status,deleted sms status like that message tracking can we done?.

Comment: Sorry not much idea about SMS related API's.