# Does Microsoft provides any way to get the list of running Processes under Windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I know that there was no way to get a list of running processes till Windows Phone 7 and in a way my question is similar to [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699050/how-to-list-running-processes-in-windows-phone-7). However, I just happened to look a link on [windowsphonehacker](http://windowsphonehacker.com/articles/exclusive_wph_taskviewer_released_video-05-14-11) which displays a list of running processes on Windows phone and I'm not very sure I got how he did this. Does Windows 8 provide any way to get the list of running processes if not control them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no supported APIs for this on Windows Phone 8.

(By the looks of it that process viewer uses some unsupported APIs - which are blocked if you were ever were to submit an app containing them to the Store).

Answer (score 1):

> Naturally, this will require a developer-unlocked device.

So, sure, you can call *verboten* api functions.  You just need to reverse-engineer which ones are available on a phone.  Kinda typical of these kind of blog posts, they never tell you what you really want to know.  You can probably get somewhere by copying the operating system DLLs off the phone and running Dumpbin.exe /exports on them.