# How to find running process details?

Tags: windows-phone-8

i need to get the running process on windows phone 8. and also the details of each process like.

1. Memory usage
2. CPU usage
3. Running time

and what if i want to kill any process by user action

and also total used and free memory and CPU usage status

help required
regards

Comment: Does WP8 support WMI?

Comment: spent some time to google this but nothing find valuable about window phone 8

Comment: Why people are trying to close this question? i am searching for this, for almost a day now but no luck :(

Comment: ... Because it's already been answered and is a duplicate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Microsoft provides any way to get the list of running Processes under Windows phone 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887461/does-microsoft-provides-any-way-to-get-the-list-of-running-processes-under-windo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows Phone, applications are sandboxed. You can get the amount of memory your own application uses, but that's about it. You can't get any kind of information about the other applications. Of course, it also means you can't kill them.

If you ever wondered why there isn't any task manager app on the marketplace, now you know.